# tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath: getting a nil indexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have implemented the `tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:` function, however i experience intermittently the `indexPath` passed to this function is nil. When i try to access `indexPath.row` , its get a value 18446744073709551615.

I am querying for the object in the array I use to build the table. and getting the crash -`-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 18446744073709551615 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'`

There was a case where I was reloading my table using `[table reloadData]` an editAction call then would get passed a nil indexPath, however this is still intermittently happening.

Is there any way i can enforce the correct indexPath to be passed to `tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Because you array has no value print your array before apply any action

Comment: Array is populated, IndexPath is coming nil.

Comment: Did you implement the method `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: No have not implemented that

Comment: check on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27856196/4831524

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement this `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle` method where data array need to be adjusted.

For details look at this article [Inserting and Deleting Rows and Sections](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1)

You can handle this by removing the item corresponding to 
the row from `data` array at first and then sending deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: to the table view.

Try to insert below lines of code inside `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if ( editingStyle== UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

      // remove item from array at first 
      [dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      // then delete table row from tableview
      [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   }
}
```

Hope it will work!